# Problem When I try to publish my Iphone app to appstore

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I have problem :(

the application is work fine similar device.

but when I try to upload .zip file this error is come .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest to use the Xcode organizer to upload your apps. Because it's impossible that such things (upload iphone simulator build) will happen.

1. Select Device as Target in the Build settings pop-down.
2. Select `Build and Archive` in the Build menu of xcode
3. Select the app in Xcode organizer, and use the `Validate...` button.
4. Log in to itunes connect when prompted.
5. `Submit...` app.
6. Be rich

Answer (score 1):

Build your app for mobile devices - armv architecture (Left Top corner in xCode -> dropdown box -> select Device). Looks like you made build for iphone simulator and try to post this on AppStore :-)

Comment: Ohh. maybe you also don't have certifactes and provision profile. For deployment to appstore you should have Distubution profile. Learn basic firstly - http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html